# How to select a Pyspark column and append it as new rows in the data frame?

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, pyspark

I have a JSON file and I want to do some ETL tasks.
I want to extract a column and append its values as new rows in the data frame.
for example, if I have a data frame like this:

```
-----------------------------------------------------------------
|name    |    last    |                  father                 |
-----------------------------------------------------------------
| daniel |  allardice | {'name': 'george', 'last': 'allardice'} |
-----------------------------------------------------------------
```

I want to turn it to:

```
----------------------------
|    name    |    last     |
----------------------------
|   daniel   |  allardice  |
----------------------------
|   george   |  allardice  |
----------------------------
```

How can I do this by UDF in PySpark?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you try with the below code

```
from pyspark.sql import functions as F

df_1 = df.select("name","last");

df_2 = df.select(F.col('father').getItem('name').alias('name'), F.col('father')['last'].alias('last'));

result = df_1.union(df_2);
```

Comment: Thanks. What can i do if instead of JSON it would be a Row() type?